# Suggested web development language and frameworks for a newbie with iOS experience

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm a newbie to web development (although I have built basic sites long ago using HTML, CSS, hacked various CMS's etc) and was wondering what language and associated framework is best to go with for a data driven web service with a dynamic UI (i.e. AJAX-ey effects) which I hope will scale at some stage in the future. I am fairly proficient in iOS development so am comfortable with Object Orientated development and the Model View Controller paradigm. Any advice and/or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Don't learn a language by learning a framework. Do basic non-framework programming in your language of choice first. THEN jump into the framework. Otherwise you're laboring under the double burden of unfamiliar language AND unfamiliar environment.

Basically, learn to drive first, THEN pimp out your ride.

Comment: Thanks Marc - good, clear advice. Any thoughts on language? I am in the process of playing around with a few anyway so will certainly be taking into account what feels good.

Comment: I would go with php, but I'm bias since I use php. look closely at the object model in both php and asp.net, they are not the same.

Comment: Most of my recent development work has been in PHP, though I'd much prefer to use Perl. Can't say much about Ruby or Python, never having used them before. PHP's a decent language, with a lot of warts, but Perl's got better overall design.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the Cocoa libraries, you might consider using [Sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) which has a design that is highly informed by Cocoa. It also has the added bonus of being rather forward looking (aka: the new hotness) and is at the point of becoming a serious tool (ie: [Apple uses it for mobile.me](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12412946/Projects-Using-SproutCore)  ) but still new enough that it is under active development by excited, passionate and skilled developers.

Also, as an aside to everyone advocating learning the basics. For many of us, the best way to learn something well is to have a real project and learn by building. Sproutcore seems like a good option for someone familiar with iOS development.

Comment: thanks Ivar. Hadn't come across that yet but it looks very interesting.

Comment: David, adding to the Sproutcore theme, if you are interested in minimizing your attack surface, learning Javascript is probably the best route. In addition to several great clientside frameworks, serverside Javascript has moved from simply 'viable' to very popular and is supported by several cloud platforms - see [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest framework in my opinion is [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) and the docs are fantastic but this is really a subjective question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Marc B, first master your language, then you could start using a framework.

as a language the two obvious choices are either asp.net, or php, both have their advantages and disadvantages... you have some reading to do, a simple google search will provide you with plenty of info. there is no one size fits all in this department. look at some code examples, see what you feel comfortable about.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. Yup my reading list is already sizable.